# what is the maximum frequency does the virtex 6 support

Tags: xilinx

what maximum frequency does the [Xilinx Virtex-6](http://www.xilinx.com/products/silicon-devices/fpga/virtex-6/index.htm) support.How can i know  that.

As I was working with Xilinx, I want to know the range of frequency it supports.

Comment: Have you tried the datasheet?

Comment: i have gone through the xilinx datasheet, the frequency depends upon the speed grade.

Comment: i want know that speed grade is fixed for the designs. some designs speed grade support from frequency for example qdr11+ and ddr3. if the both designs are working on the same speed grade but the frequency supported are different

Answer (score 2):

It's not easy to determine maximum frequency of any FPGA. It depends on design, DSP usage, etc. If you want to know what is maximum clocking frequency, you should refer to a document called "DC and Switching Characteristics" for Virtex-6.